# Finding number from list that respects conditions

Tags: python

I need to code a script that chooses a number from a user input (list) depending on two conditions:

1. Is a multiple of 3
2. Is the smallest of all numbers

Here is what I've done so far

```
if a % 3 == 0 and a < b:
  print (a)
a = int(input())
r = list(map(int, input().split()))
result(a, r)
```

The problem is I need to create a loop that keeps verifying these conditions for the (x) number of inputs.

Comment: Step one: create a sublist of elements which are divisible by 3. Step 2: find the smallest element.

Comment: Can you explain how this code is related to what you want to do?

Comment: What is `a` in your code? I'd suppose that you want `print(min(x for x in r if x % 3 == 0))` after list `r` is read.

Comment: How exactly do you want the result to depend on these two conditions?  Do you want all the numbers that match either condition, or a single number that matches the second condition after having excluded those which don't match the first condition, or a single number that matches both conditions (with an error if there is no such number)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `a` to be values within `r` rather than its own input.  Here's an example of iterating through `r` and checking which numbers are multiples of 3, and of finding the minimum of all the numbers (not necessarily only those which are multiples of 3):

```
r = list(map(int, input().split()))
for a in r:
    if a % 3 == 0:
        print(f"Multiple of 3: {a}")
print(f"Smallest of numbers: {min(r)}")
```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
Multiple of 3: 3
Multiple of 3: 6
Multiple of 3: 9
Multiple of 3: 0
Smallest of numbers: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in one line – or through [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) – can improve performance through optimizing memory allocation:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# The following is a generator
# Also: you need to decide if you want 0 to be included
all_threes = (x for x in my_list if x%3==0)
min_number = min(my_list)
```